# Looker studio compare previous period with percentage number

Tags: percentage, looker-studio

When I use compare with previous period function in looker studio, the none percentage number is working fine, but for percentage number is not showing right, for example this month is 2% last month is 1.3% the difference should be 0.7% instead of (2%-1.3%)/1.3%

I try all the ways in the compare with last period function in looker studio none of them work

Comment: can you share the formula you are using to get the %?